# Using of System.Speech.Synthesis; System.Speech.Recognition;

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, text-to-speech, system.speech.recognition

I've using of `System.Speech.Synthesis;` and  `System.Speech.Recognition;` for .NET `C#` Windows Form Application, but I can't find information, if Microsoft David, Mark, Zira Windows System Voices, can be used as Text-To-Speech and `System.Speech.Recognition;` as voice recognition tools in application for commercial, or at least scientific projects.

I'm not looking for another TTS tools, because these tools completely satisfy the desired result, but I do not quite understand their status for using

if you look into **[mono project list](http://go-mono.com/status/)** you can find there also system.speech and recognition **[here](http://www.go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Speech)**, at the same time it is **[bundled with Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_speech_synthesizers)** so I'm not really understand what it means, and how this rules works

Would be good if you can help me figure out with this information

Comment: Seems like I just saw this question...

Comment: The asker seems to want legal/licensing advice on using Microsoft tools in a commercial application.  That seems off-topic to me.

Comment: @DangerZone Hello,  question is simple, can you use `System.Speech.Synthesis;` for commercial cross-platform app with mono for example if Speech.Synthesis is sold and bundled with Windows, or for example just sell windows form application which uses this tools...

Comment: @DonBoitnott  Hello, you saw it, because I wrote it again. And  no, my  question is based on fact that the mono project allows you to use it this way, so I'm not asking legal/licensing advice, I'm asking about your own experience with this tools and given ability to use it

Comment: Still no answer for that?..